# Uniqueness of Arrow-Debreu Equilibria

Tags: general-equilibrium

I have been trying to figure out conditions on the preferences of traders in an exchange economy such that the equilibrium prices are unique but I cannot be sure since all sources seem to be contradicting each other. On the [Arrow-Debreu wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrow%E2%80%93Debreu_model) it says "In general, there may be many equilibria; however, with extra assumptions on consumer preferences, namely that their utility functions be strongly concave and twice continuously differentiable, a unique equilibrium exists." However, the Sonnenschein–Mantel–Debreu theorem does not tells us that the excess demand curve inherits the shape of the utility functions.

I do understand that for utilities satisfying the gross substitutes conditions the equilibrium prices are unique but are prices unique if we assume concave and twice differentiable utility functions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pure exchange economy: Given an initial endowment are multiple equilibria possible?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/19289/pure-exchange-economy-given-an-initial-endowment-are-multiple-equilibria-possib)

Comment: What is written on Wikipedia about uniqueness is simply wrong. The most common sufficient condition for equilibrium uniqueness is that all goods are gross substitutes for every consumer.